# Can someone tell me why the given code below gets into an infinite loop?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Do While x2 <> Abs(x1) - Abs(f1 / f2)     
   f1 = (4 * x1) - (16 / (x1 ^ 2))
   f2 = 4 + (32 / (x1 ^ 3))
   x2 = (x1) - (f1 / f2)
   ' Output to Screen
   Cells(counter, 1) = x1
   Cells(counter, 3) = f1
   Cells(counter, 4) = f2      
   counter = counter + 1
Loop
```

The above loop has become infinite. How do I get out of it? What is the error in there?

Comment: because x2 never equals Abs(x1) - Abs(f1 / f2). With non integer numbers there is a good change that it could be 100000th off or some other decimal.  If you can get away with it us `>=` or `<=` instead.

Comment: Another option - use a Do While that rounds your numbers to an acceptable margin.

Answer (score 0):

A better structure may be to have your loop condition be the difference against the target.  Also, I placed some error handling in to avoid troublesome conditions.

```
Do While difference > 0.001
   f1 = (4 * x1) - (16 / (x1 ^ 2))
   f2 = 4 + (32 / (x1 ^ 3))
   x2 = (x1) - (f1 / f2)
   ' Output to Screen
   Cells(counter, 1) = x1
   Cells(counter, 3) = f1
   Cells(counter, 4) = f2
   counter = counter + 1

   'Avoid runaway condition
   If counter > 1000 Then
      MsgBox "WARNING!" & Chr(10) & "1000 cycles exceeded"
      Exit Do
   End If
   'Divison by zero
   If f2 = 0 Then
      MsgBox "ERROR!" & Chr(10) & "Divion by zero"
      Exit Do
   End If

   'calculate difference from target
   difference = Abs(x2 - (Abs(x1) - Abs(f1 / f2)))
Loop
```

You could also use the round function to do something like this...

```
Do While round(x2 - (Abs(x1) - Abs(f1 / f2)),3) <> 0
```

or this...

```
Do While round(x2,3) <> round(Abs(x1) - Abs(f1 / f2),3)
```

Which is the closest to your original code

Comment: I use the code and the error I get is 'end if without block if'. How do I resolve it?

Comment: @BhavyaSVadlamani As the error suggests, it means something is wrong with your `if` structure. The code as posted should work perfectly fine.  You can remove the if statements, they aren't entirely necessary, but they're good to include if you can.